# Como habilitar um botão, apenas quando aceitar os termos

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Bom, estou fazendo um site de compras de produtos virtuais, e preciso que meus clientes aceitem o "Termo de uso". o método que usei foi esse

```
<input name="ck_permissao"  type="checkbox" id="ck_permissao" value="checkbox" onclick="return confere()" /><a>TERMOS DE USO</a>







                <div class="col-md-4"> 
                    <div class="product"> 
                        <div class="image"> 
                            <img src="<?php echo $vip_img_01 ?>" alt="WorldNetwork" class="img-fluid"> 
                        </div> 
                        <div class="name"><?php echo $vip_nome_01 ?> - <?php echo $vip_dias_01 ?></div> 
                        <div class="price"><?php echo $vip_preco_01 ?></div> 
                        <div class="footer"> 
                            <a href="<?php echo $vip_detalhes_01 ?>" target="_blank">
                            <input disabled="disabled" name="ck_incluir" type="button" id="ck_incluir" value="COMPRAR"/>
                            </a>
                        </div> 
                    </div> 
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4"> 
                    <div class="product"> 
                        <div class="image"> 
                            <img src="<?php echo $vip_img_02 ?>" alt="WorldNetwork" class="img-fluid"> 
                        </div> 
                        <div class="name"><?php echo $vip_nome_02 ?> - <?php echo $vip_dias_02 ?></div> 
                        <div class="price"><?php echo $vip_preco_02 ?></div> 
                        <div class="footer"> 
                            <a href="<?php echo $vip_detalhes_02 ?>" target="_blank">
                            <input disabled="disabled" name="ck_incluir" type="button" id="ck_incluir" value="COMPRAR"/>
                            </a>
                        </div> 
                    </div> 
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4"> 
                    <div class="product"> 
                        <div class="image"> 
                            <img src="<?php echo $vip_img_03 ?>" alt="WorldNetwork" class="img-fluid"> 
                        </div> 
                        <div class="name"><?php echo $vip_nome_03 ?> - <?php echo $vip_dias_03 ?></div> 
                        <div class="price"><?php echo $vip_preco_03 ?></div> 
                        <div class="footer"> 
                            <a href="<?php echo $vip_detalhes_03 ?>" target="_blank">
                            <input disabled="disabled" name="ck_incluir" type="button" id="ck_incluir" value="COMPRAR"/>
                            </a>
                        </div> 
                    </div> 
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4"> 
                    <div class="product"> 
                        <div class="image"> 
                            <img src="<?php echo $vip_img_04 ?>" alt="WorldNetwork" class="img-fluid"> 
                        </div> 
                        <div class="name"><?php echo $vip_nome_04 ?> - <?php echo $vip_dias_04 ?></div> 
                        <div class="price"><?php echo $vip_preco_04 ?></div> 
                        <div class="footer"> 
                            <a href="<?php echo $vip_detalhes_04 ?>" target="_blank">
                            <input disabled="disabled" name="ck_incluir" type="button" id="ck_incluir" value="COMPRAR"/>
                            </a>
                        </div> 
                    </div> 
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4"> 
                    <div class="product"> 
                        <div class="image"> 
                            <img src="<?php echo $vip_img_05 ?>" alt="WorldNetwork" class="img-fluid"> 
                        </div> 
                        <div class="name"><?php echo $vip_nome_05 ?> - <?php echo $vip_dias_05 ?></div> 
                        <div class="price"><?php echo $vip_preco_05 ?></div> 
                        <div class="footer"> 
                            <a href="<?php echo $vip_detalhes_05 ?>" target="_blank">
                            <input disabled="disabled" name="ck_incluir" type="button" id="ck_incluir" value="COMPRAR"/>
                            </a>
                        </div> 
                    </div> 
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4"> 
                    <div class="product"> 
                        <div class="image"> 
                            <img src="<?php echo $vip_img_06 ?>" alt="WorldNetwork" class="img-fluid"> 
                        </div> 
                        <div class="name"><?php echo $vip_nome_06 ?> - <?php echo $vip_dias_06 ?></div> 
                        <div class="price"><?php echo $vip_preco_06 ?></div> 
                        <div class="footer"> 
                            <a href="<?php echo $vip_detalhes_06 ?>" target="_blank">
                            <input disabled="disabled" name="ck_incluir" type="button" id="ck_incluir" value="COMPRAR"/>
                            </a>
                        </div> 
                    </div> 
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4"> 
                    <div class="product"> 
                        <div class="image"> 
                            <img src="<?php echo $vip_img_07 ?>" alt="WorldNetwork" class="img-fluid"> 
                        </div> 
                        <div class="name"><?php echo $vip_nome_07 ?> - <?php echo $vip_dias_07 ?></div> 
                        <div class="price"><?php echo $vip_preco_06 ?></div> 
                        <div class="footer"> 
                            <a href="<?php echo $vip_detalhes_07 ?>" target="_blank">
                            <input disabled="disabled" name="ck_incluir" type="button" id="ck_incluir" value="COMPRAR"/>
                            </a>
                        </div> 
                    </div> 
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4"> 
                    <div class="product"> 
                        <div class="image"> 
                            <img src="<?php echo $vip_img_08 ?>" alt="WorldNetwork" class="img-fluid"> 
                        </div> 
                        <div class="name"><?php echo $vip_nome_08 ?> - <?php echo $vip_dias_08 ?></div> 
                        <div class="price"><?php echo $vip_preco_08 ?></div> 
                        <div class="footer"> 
                            <a href="<?php echo $vip_detalhes_08 ?>" target="_blank">
                            <input disabled="disabled" name="ck_incluir" type="button" id="ck_incluir" value="COMPRAR"/>
                            </a>
                        </div> 
                    </div> 
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4"> 
                    <div class="product"> 
                        <div class="image"> 
                            <img src="<?php echo $vip_img_09 ?>" alt="WorldNetwork" class="img-fluid"> 
                        </div> 
                        <div class="name"><?php echo $vip_nome_09 ?> - <?php echo $vip_dias_09 ?></div> 
                        <div class="price"><?php echo $vip_preco_09 ?></div> 
                        <div class="footer"> 
                            <a href="<?php echo $vip_detalhes_09 ?>" target="_blank">
                            <input disabled="disabled" name="ck_incluir" type="button" id="ck_incluir" value="COMPRAR"/>
                            </a>
                        </div> 
                    </div> 
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4"> 
                    <div class="product"> 
                        <div class="image"> 
                            <img src="<?php echo $vip_img_10 ?>" alt="WorldNetwork" class="img-fluid"> 
                        </div> 
                        <div class="name"><?php echo $vip_nome_10 ?> - <?php echo $vip_dias_10 ?></div> 
                        <div class="price"><?php echo $vip_preco_10 ?></div> 
                        <div class="footer"> 
                            <a href="<?php echo $vip_detalhes_10 ?>" target="_blank">
                            <input disabled="disabled" name="ck_incluir" type="button" id="ck_incluir" value="COMPRAR"/>
                            </a>
                        </div> 
                    </div> 
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4"> 
                    <div class="product"> 
                        <div class="image"> 
                            <img src="<?php echo $vip_img_11 ?>" alt="WorldNetwork" class="img-fluid"> 
                        </div> 
                        <div class="name"><?php echo $vip_nome_11 ?> - <?php echo $vip_dias_11 ?></div> 
                        <div class="price"><?php echo $vip_preco_11 ?></div> 
                        <div class="footer"> 
                            <a href="<?php echo $vip_detalhes_11 ?>" target="_blank">
                            <input disabled="disabled" name="ck_incluir" type="button" id="ck_incluir" value="COMPRAR"/>
                            </a>
                        </div> 
                    </div> 
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4"> 
                    <div class="product"> 
                        <div class="image"> 
                            <img src="<?php echo $vip_img_12 ?>" alt="WorldNetwork" class="img-fluid"> 
                        </div> 
                        <div class="name"><?php echo $vip_nome_12 ?> - <?php echo $vip_dias_12 ?></div> 
                        <div class="price"><?php echo $vip_preco_12 ?></div> 
                        <div class="footer"> 
                            <a href="<?php echo $vip_detalhes_12 ?>" target="_blank">
                            <input disabled="disabled" name="ck_incluir" type="button" id="ck_incluir" value="COMPRAR"/>
                            </a>
                        </div> 
                    </div> 
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4"> 
                    <div class="product"> 
                        <div class="image"> 
                            <img src="<?php echo $vip_img_13 ?>" alt="WorldNetwork" class="img-fluid"> 
                        </div> 
                        <div class="name"><?php echo $vip_nome_13 ?> - <?php echo $vip_dias_13 ?></div> 
                        <div class="price"><?php echo $vip_preco_13 ?></div> 
                        <div class="footer"> 
                            <a href="<?php echo $vip_detalhes_13 ?>" target="_blank">
                            <input disabled="disabled" name="ck_incluir" type="button" id="ck_incluir" value="COMPRAR"/>
                            </a>
                        </div> 
                    </div> 
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4"> 
                    <div class="product"> 
                        <div class="image"> 
                            <img src="<?php echo $vip_img_14 ?>" alt="WorldNetwork" class="img-fluid"> 
                        </div> 
                        <div class="name"><?php echo $vip_nome_14 ?> - <?php echo $vip_dias_14 ?></div> 
                        <div class="price"><?php echo $vip_preco_14 ?></div> 
                        <div class="footer"> 
                            <a href="<?php echo $vip_detalhes_14 ?>" target="_blank">
                            <input disabled="disabled" name="ck_incluir" type="button" id="ck_incluir" value="COMPRAR"/>
                            </a>
                        </div> 
                    </div> 
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4"> 
                    <div class="product"> 
                        <div class="image"> 
                            <img src="<?php echo $vip_img_15 ?>" alt="WorldNetwork" class="img-fluid"> 
                        </div> 
                        <div class="name"><?php echo $vip_nome_15 ?> - <?php echo $vip_dias_15 ?></div> 
                        <div class="price"><?php echo $vip_preco_15 ?></div> 
                        <div class="footer"> 
                            <a href="<?php echo $vip_detalhes_15 ?>" target="_blank">
                            <input disabled="disabled" name="ck_incluir" type="button" id="ck_incluir" value="COMPRAR"/>
                            </a>
                        </div> 
                    </div> 
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4"> 
                    <div class="product"> 
                        <div class="image"> 
                            <img src="<?php echo $vip_img_16 ?>" alt="WorldNetwork" class="img-fluid"> 
                        </div> 
                        <div class="name"><?php echo $vip_nome_16 ?> - <?php echo $vip_dias_16 ?></div> 
                        <div class="price"><?php echo $vip_preco_16 ?></div> 
                        <div class="footer"> 
                            <a href="<?php echo $vip_detalhes_16 ?>" target="_blank">
                            <input disabled="disabled" name="ck_incluir" type="button" id="ck_incluir" value="COMPRAR"/>
                            </a>
                        </div> 
                    </div> 
                </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
function confere() {
    document.getElementById('ck_incluir').disabled = ! document.getElementById('ck_permissao').checked;
}
</script>
```

Bom a unica coisa que esta dando errado, e que apenas afeta o primeiro button...

http://prntscr.com/i7h5dm

http://prntscr.com/i7h5hh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está em usar o mesmo `id` para vários elementos, o que é uma prática errada.

> Um `id` deve ser único em uma página.

Você pode usar o jQuery para capturar os botões pelo `name`, já que todos eles possuem o mesmo (ou poderia ser por uma `class` caso você trocasse todos os `id` por `class`):

```
function confere(){
   $('input[name="ck_incluir"]').prop("disabled", !document.getElementById('ck_permissao').checked);
}
```

Para que seu código fique melhor escrito, sugiro remova todos os `id` dos botões; ou então remova os `name` e troque os `id` por `class`:

```
<input disabled="disabled" type="button" class="ck_incluir" value="COMPRAR"/>
                                           ↑
```

Então, na função, troque o seletor:

```
function confere(){
   $('.ck_incluir').prop("disabled", !document.getElementById('ck_permissao').checked);
}
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
function confere() {
   $('.ck_incluir').prop("disabled", !document.getElementById('ck_permissao').checked);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="ck_permissao"  type="checkbox" id="ck_permissao" value="checkbox" onclick="return confere()" /><a>TERMOS DE USO</a>

 <div class="col-md-4"> 
     <div class="product"> 
         <div class="image"> 
             <img src="<?php echo $vip_img_01 ?>" alt="WorldNetwork" class="img-fluid"> 
         </div> 
         <div class="name"><?php echo $vip_nome_01 ?> - <?php echo $vip_dias_01 ?></div> 
         <div class="price"><?php echo $vip_preco_01 ?></div> 
         <div class="footer"> 
             <a href="<?php echo $vip_detalhes_01 ?>" target="_blank">
             <input disabled="disabled" type="button" class="ck_incluir" value="COMPRAR"/>
             </a>
         </div> 
     </div> 
 </div>

 <div class="col-md-4"> 
     <div class="product"> 
         <div class="image"> 
             <img src="<?php echo $vip_img_02 ?>" alt="WorldNetwork" class="img-fluid"> 
         </div> 
         <div class="name"><?php echo $vip_nome_02 ?> - <?php echo $vip_dias_02 ?></div> 
         <div class="price"><?php echo $vip_preco_02 ?></div> 
         <div class="footer"> 
             <a href="<?php echo $vip_detalhes_02 ?>" target="_blank">
             <input disabled="disabled" type="button" class="ck_incluir" value="COMPRAR"/>
             </a>
         </div> 
     </div> 
 </div>

 <div class="col-md-4"> 
     <div class="product"> 
         <div class="image"> 
             <img src="<?php echo $vip_img_03 ?>" alt="WorldNetwork" class="img-fluid"> 
         </div> 
         <div class="name"><?php echo $vip_nome_03 ?> - <?php echo $vip_dias_03 ?></div> 
         <div class="price"><?php echo $vip_preco_03 ?></div> 
         <div class="footer"> 
             <a href="<?php echo $vip_detalhes_03 ?>" target="_blank">
             <input disabled="disabled" type="button" class="ck_incluir" value="COMPRAR"/>
             </a>
         </div> 
     </div> 
 </div>

 <div class="col-md-4"> 
     <div class="product"> 
         <div class="image"> 
             <img src="<?php echo $vip_img_04 ?>" alt="WorldNetwork" class="img-fluid"> 
         </div> 
         <div class="name"><?php echo $vip_nome_04 ?> - <?php echo $vip_dias_04 ?></div> 
         <div class="price"><?php echo $vip_preco_04 ?></div> 
         <div class="footer"> 
             <a href="<?php echo $vip_detalhes_04 ?>" target="_blank">
             <input disabled="disabled" type="button" class="ck_incluir" value="COMPRAR"/>
             </a>
         </div> 
     </div> 
 </div>

 <div class="col-md-4"> 
     <div class="product"> 
         <div class="image"> 
             <img src="<?php echo $vip_img_05 ?>" alt="WorldNetwork" class="img-fluid"> 
         </div> 
         <div class="name"><?php echo $vip_nome_05 ?> - <?php echo $vip_dias_05 ?></div> 
         <div class="price"><?php echo $vip_preco_05 ?></div> 
         <div class="footer"> 
             <a href="<?php echo $vip_detalhes_05 ?>" target="_blank">
             <input disabled="disabled" type="button" class="ck_incluir" value="COMPRAR"/>
             </a>
         </div> 
     </div> 
 </div>

 <div class="col-md-4"> 
     <div class="product"> 
         <div class="image"> 
             <img src="<?php echo $vip_img_06 ?>" alt="WorldNetwork" class="img-fluid"> 
         </div> 
         <div class="name"><?php echo $vip_nome_06 ?> - <?php echo $vip_dias_06 ?></div> 
         <div class="price"><?php echo $vip_preco_06 ?></div> 
         <div class="footer"> 
             <a href="<?php echo $vip_detalhes_06 ?>" target="_blank">
             <input disabled="disabled" type="button" class="ck_incluir" value="COMPRAR"/>
             </a>
         </div> 
     </div> 
 </div>

 <div class="col-md-4"> 
     <div class="product"> 
         <div class="image"> 
             <img src="<?php echo $vip_img_07 ?>" alt="WorldNetwork" class="img-fluid"> 
         </div> 
         <div class="name"><?php echo $vip_nome_07 ?> - <?php echo $vip_dias_07 ?></div> 
         <div class="price"><?php echo $vip_preco_06 ?></div> 
         <div class="footer"> 
             <a href="<?php echo $vip_detalhes_07 ?>" target="_blank">
             <input disabled="disabled" type="button" class="ck_incluir" value="COMPRAR"/>
             </a>
         </div> 
     </div> 
 </div>

 <div class="col-md-4"> 
     <div class="product"> 
         <div class="image"> 
             <img src="<?php echo $vip_img_08 ?>" alt="WorldNetwork" class="img-fluid"> 
         </div> 
         <div class="name"><?php echo $vip_nome_08 ?> - <?php echo $vip_dias_08 ?></div> 
         <div class="price"><?php echo $vip_preco_08 ?></div> 
         <div class="footer"> 
             <a href="<?php echo $vip_detalhes_08 ?>" target="_blank">
             <input disabled="disabled" type="button" class="ck_incluir" value="COMPRAR"/>
             </a>
         </div> 
     </div> 
 </div>

 <div class="col-md-4"> 
     <div class="product"> 
         <div class="image"> 
             <img src="<?php echo $vip_img_09 ?>" alt="WorldNetwork" class="img-fluid"> 
         </div> 
         <div class="name"><?php echo $vip_nome_09 ?> - <?php echo $vip_dias_09 ?></div> 
         <div class="price"><?php echo $vip_preco_09 ?></div> 
         <div class="footer"> 
             <a href="<?php echo $vip_detalhes_09 ?>" target="_blank">
             <input disabled="disabled" type="button" class="ck_incluir" value="COMPRAR"/>
             </a>
         </div> 
     </div> 
 </div>

 <div class="col-md-4"> 
     <div class="product"> 
         <div class="image"> 
             <img src="<?php echo $vip_img_10 ?>" alt="WorldNetwork" class="img-fluid"> 
         </div> 
         <div class="name"><?php echo $vip_nome_10 ?> - <?php echo $vip_dias_10 ?></div> 
         <div class="price"><?php echo $vip_preco_10 ?></div> 
         <div class="footer"> 
             <a href="<?php echo $vip_detalhes_10 ?>" target="_blank">
             <input disabled="disabled" type="button" class="ck_incluir" value="COMPRAR"/>
             </a>
         </div> 
     </div> 
 </div>

 <div class="col-md-4"> 
     <div class="product"> 
         <div class="image"> 
             <img src="<?php echo $vip_img_11 ?>" alt="WorldNetwork" class="img-fluid"> 
         </div> 
         <div class="name"><?php echo $vip_nome_11 ?> - <?php echo $vip_dias_11 ?></div> 
         <div class="price"><?php echo $vip_preco_11 ?></div> 
         <div class="footer"> 
             <a href="<?php echo $vip_detalhes_11 ?>" target="_blank">
             <input disabled="disabled" type="button" class="ck_incluir" value="COMPRAR"/>
             </a>
         </div> 
     </div> 
 </div>

 <div class="col-md-4"> 
     <div class="product"> 
         <div class="image"> 
             <img src="<?php echo $vip_img_12 ?>" alt="WorldNetwork" class="img-fluid"> 
         </div> 
         <div class="name"><?php echo $vip_nome_12 ?> - <?php echo $vip_dias_12 ?></div> 
         <div class="price"><?php echo $vip_preco_12 ?></div> 
         <div class="footer"> 
             <a href="<?php echo $vip_detalhes_12 ?>" target="_blank">
             <input disabled="disabled" type="button" class="ck_incluir" value="COMPRAR"/>
             </a>
         </div> 
     </div> 
 </div>

 <div class="col-md-4"> 
     <div class="product"> 
         <div class="image"> 
             <img src="<?php echo $vip_img_13 ?>" alt="WorldNetwork" class="img-fluid"> 
         </div> 
         <div class="name"><?php echo $vip_nome_13 ?> - <?php echo $vip_dias_13 ?></div> 
         <div class="price"><?php echo $vip_preco_13 ?></div> 
         <div class="footer"> 
             <a href="<?php echo $vip_detalhes_13 ?>" target="_blank">
             <input disabled="disabled" type="button" class="ck_incluir" value="COMPRAR"/>
             </a>
         </div> 
     </div> 
 </div>

 <div class="col-md-4"> 
     <div class="product"> 
         <div class="image"> 
             <img src="<?php echo $vip_img_14 ?>" alt="WorldNetwork" class="img-fluid"> 
         </div> 
         <div class="name"><?php echo $vip_nome_14 ?> - <?php echo $vip_dias_14 ?></div> 
         <div class="price"><?php echo $vip_preco_14 ?></div> 
         <div class="footer"> 
             <a href="<?php echo $vip_detalhes_14 ?>" target="_blank">
             <input disabled="disabled" type="button" class="ck_incluir" value="COMPRAR"/>
             </a>
         </div> 
     </div> 
 </div>

 <div class="col-md-4"> 
     <div class="product"> 
         <div class="image"> 
             <img src="<?php echo $vip_img_15 ?>" alt="WorldNetwork" class="img-fluid"> 
         </div> 
         <div class="name"><?php echo $vip_nome_15 ?> - <?php echo $vip_dias_15 ?></div> 
         <div class="price"><?php echo $vip_preco_15 ?></div> 
         <div class="footer"> 
             <a href="<?php echo $vip_detalhes_15 ?>" target="_blank">
             <input disabled="disabled" type="button" class="ck_incluir" value="COMPRAR"/>
             </a>
         </div> 
     </div> 
 </div>

 <div class="col-md-4"> 
     <div class="product"> 
         <div class="image"> 
             <img src="<?php echo $vip_img_16 ?>" alt="WorldNetwork" class="img-fluid"> 
         </div> 
         <div class="name"><?php echo $vip_nome_16 ?> - <?php echo $vip_dias_16 ?></div> 
         <div class="price"><?php echo $vip_preco_16 ?></div> 
         <div class="footer"> 
             <a href="<?php echo $vip_detalhes_16 ?>" target="_blank">
             <input disabled="disabled" type="button" class="ck_incluir" value="COMPRAR"/>
             </a>
         </div> 
     </div> 
 </div>
```

Comment: E o input do checkbox tenho que mudar algo nele ?

Comment: @zlDeath Não precisa. Pode deixar como está.

Comment: @zlDeath Poxa, eu não tenho Skype. Coloquei um exemplo funcional na resposta. Dá uma olhada e me diz.

Comment: GOD !!! Deu certo, muito obrigado

Comment: Tem como aparecer alguma mensagem avisando que precisa aceitar os termos ?

Comment: @zlDeath Como assim?

Comment: Tipo "Para continuar voce precisa acessar os termos !"

Comment: @zlDeath Pode colocar esse texto ao lado do checkbox, não?

Comment: Teria algum meio de contato para eu te explicar melhor ?

Comment: Queria fazer tipo isso "https://prnt.sc/i8h7un"
Fazer aparecer uma mensagem (tipo um tooltip) quando os buttons estiverem desativados. 
E quando ativar o checkbox dos termos a mensagem desaparecer.
Deu pra entender ?

Comment: @zlDeath Desculpe a demora em responder. Tem como fazer isso sim, mas seria melhor que fosse um assunto para outra pergunta. Vou dar uma dica: faz uma pergunta específica, não precisa explicar todo o seu sistema, apenas pergunte algo assim: "Como mostrar um tooltip em botões desabilitados antes que o checkbox esteja marcado?".. algo desse tipo, e inclua na pergunta a imagem de exemplo e o código que vc já tem. Assim os colegas poderão ajudar e eu vou tentar tb. Abs!

Comment: segue o link https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/274123/tooltip-quando-estiver-desativado